# Entity Framework 6 optimal eager loading strategy

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

My application has a single aggregate route for an entity in the form of Parent with a child collection.

When I load my object with EF 6 I would like to eager load the graph but utilize the `Find` method to check whether the object already exists in my `DbContext`.

### Example one

Parent object will be returned from context if found else parent object will be returned from the database. **Child collection is never eager loaded from database**.

```
var parentObj = _context.ParentEntities.Find(id);
```

### Example two

The parent object will be returned if it exists in the **database only**. The local context is not checked beforehand. If a record has been added to the local context already, this will be overlooked and A new object will be appended to the local context sharing the same primary key. **Child collection is always eager loaded from database.**

```
var parentObj = _context
    .ParentEntities
    .Include(p => p.Child)
    .SingleOrDefault(p => p.Id == id);
```

Am I able to achieve the benefits from both examples without having to roll my own object context interrogation logic?